# Deactivate the switch to hamburger menu (media Rule)

Tags: html, css, media-queries, html-email

In an email I'm working on, there is the following media rule which, once the screen becomes smaller than 660px collapses the normal menu (a row of a few links) into a hamburger menu.

```
@media only screen and (max-width:660px) {
.fw{
width:100% !important;
min-width:0 !important;
}
.fl{
width: 100% !important;
display: block !important;
}
.mh,
.mobile_hidden {
display: none !important;
}
.m-text-center{
text-align: center !important;
}
.dh,
.desktop_hidden {
display: block !important;
}
.mobile-border-top{
border-top: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
}
```

The menu when the screen is bigger than 660px:
[image]

The menu when the screen becomes smaller than 660px:
[image]

The problem is this is an email, and a menu collapsed into a hamburger menu loses its function because the recipient cannot open it.

I would like to deactivate this collapse, but I don't know where in the HTML code I should track this behavior. I can capture the containers using *Inspect Element*, but I don't know which attributes I should look for.

**UPDATE**: Here is the entire HTML/CSS code for the menu. I removed brand information and all the unnecessary blocks for clarity.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" e-locale="en-US" e-is-multilanguage="false" style="background: #fff; width: 100% !important; margin: 0 !important; padding: 0 !important;"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>StackOverflow Question</title>
    
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes">
    <!--[if !mso]><!--><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"><!--<![endif]-->
    <!--[if gte mso 9]>
        <xml>
        <o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
        <o:AllowPNG/>
        <o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch>
        </o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
        </xml>
    <![endif]-->
    <style>
        
        #outlook a{ padding:0; }
        
        .ReadMsgBody, .ExternalClass{
        width:100%;
        }
        
        
        .ExternalClass, .ExternalClass *, .ExternalClass p, .ExternalClass font, .ExternalClass td, .ExternalClass div, .b-message-body {
        line-height: 100%;
        }
        
        body, table, td, p, a, li, blockquote{
        -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;
        -ms-text-size-adjust:100%;
        mso-line-height-rule: exactly;
        line-height: normal;
        }
        body{
        height:100% !important;
        }
        
        table, td{
        border-collapse: collapse !important;
        mso-table-lspace:0pt;
        mso-table-rspace:0pt;
        border-spacing: 0;
        mso-line-height-rule: exactly; mso-margin-bottom-alt: 0; mso-margin-top-alt: 0;
        }
        
        img{
        -ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic;
        border:0;
        line-height:100%;
        outline:none;
        text-decoration:none;
        margin: 0;
        }
        .img{
        display: block;
        margin: 0 auto;
        max-width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        }
        
        html,
        body{
        width:100% !important;
        margin: 0 !important;
        padding: 0 !important;
        background: #fff;
        }
        .box{
        background: #fff;
        }
        
        a,
        a:link,
        a:active,
        a:visited,
        a:hover,
        .yshortcuts,
        .yshortcuts a span {
        text-decoration: none;
        font-weight: normal;
        color: #5e2674;
        }
        a[x-apple-data-detectors],
        *[lang="uri"] a {
        color: inherit !important;
        text-decoration: none !important;
        font-size: inherit !important;
        font-family: inherit !important;
        font-weight: inherit !important;
        line-height: inherit !important;
        }
        
        .text-brand,
        .text-brand a,
        a.text-brand,
        a.text-brand:link,
        a.text-brand:active,
        a.text-brand:visited,
        a.text-brand:hover{
        color: #5e2674;
        }
        .text-accent,
        .text-accent a,
        a.text-accent,
        a.text-accent:link,
        a.text-accent:active,
        a.text-accent:visited,
        a.text-accent:hover{
        color: #222222;
        }
        .text-discount,
        .text-discount a,
        a.text-discount,
        a.text-discount:link,
        a.text-discount:active,
        a.text-discount:visited,
        a.text-discount:hover{
        color: #dc3545;
        }
        .text-primary,
        a.text-primary,
        a.text-primary:link,
        a.text-primary:active,
        a.text-primary:visited,
        a.text-primary:hover{
        color: #222;
        }
        .text-secondary,
        .text-secondary a,
        a.text-secondary,
        a.text-secondary:link,
        a.text-secondary:active,
        a.text-secondary:visited,
        a.text-secondary:hover{
        color: #666;
        }
        .text-hint,
        .text-hint a,
        a.text-hint,
        a.text-hint:link,
        a.text-hint:active,
        a.text-hint:visited,
        a.text-hint:hover{
        color: #999;
        }
        .text-separator,
        .text-separator a,
        a.text-separator,
        a.text-separator:link,
        a.text-separator:active,
        a.text-separator:visited,
        a.text-separator:hover{
        color: #E0E0E0;
        }
        .text-white,
        .text-white a,
        a.text-white,
        a.text-white:link,
        a.text-white:active,
        a.text-white:visited,
        a.text-white:hover{
        color: #fff;
        }
        .text-mandatory,
        .text-mandatory a,
        a.text-mandatory,
        a.text-mandatory:link,
        a.text-mandatory:active,
        a.text-mandatory:visited,
        a.text-mandatory:hover{
        color: #ff0000;
        }
        
        .text-heading{ font-family: Nunito, sans-serif; }
        .text-body{ font-family: Nunito, sans-serif; }
        .text-bold{ font-weight: bold; }
        .text-bold a{ font-weight: bold; }
        .text-underline{ text-decoration: underline; }
        .text-stroke{ text-decoration: line-through; }
        .text-italic{ font-style: italic; }
        
        .text-small{ font-size: 11px; }
        .text-base{ font-size: 14px; }
        .text-medium{ font-size: 16px; }
        .text-large{ font-size: 32px; }
        .text-x-large{ font-size: 52px; }
        .text-xx-large{ font-size: 96px; }
        
        .text-small, .lineheight-small{ line-height: 13px; }
        .text-base, .lineheight-base{ line-height: 20px; }
        .text-medium, .lineheight-medium{ line-height: 22px; }
        .text-large, .lineheight-large{ line-height: 32px; }
        .text-x-large, .lineheight-x-large{ line-height: 52px; }
        .text-xx-large, .lineheight-xx-large{ line-height: 96px; }
        
        .text-left{ text-align: left; }
        .text-center{ text-align: center; }
        .text-right{ text-align: right; }
        .text-nowrap{ white-space: nowrap; }
        
        .trans-td{ line-height: 0; }
        .trans{ display: block; line-height: 0; }
        
        .mg{ margin: 15px; }
        .mg-t{ margin-top: 15px; }
        .mg-r{ margin-right: 15px; }
        .mg-b{ margin-bottom: 15px; }
        .mg-l{ margin-left: 15px; }
        
        .pd{ padding: 15px; }
        .pd-t{ padding-top: 15px; }
        .pd-r{ padding-right: 15px; }
        .pd-b{ padding-bottom: 15px; }
        .pd-l{ padding-left: 15px; }
        
        .table-force{ width: 100%; }
        
        .dh,
        .desktop_hidden {
        display: none;
        }
        
        @media only screen and (max-width:660px) {
        .fw{
        width:100% !important;
        min-width:0 !important;
        }
        .fl{
        width: 100% !important;
        display: block !important;
        }
        .mh,
        .mobile_hidden {
        display: none !important;
        }
        .m-text-center{
        text-align: center !important;
        }
        .dh,
        .desktop_hidden {
        display: block !important;
        }
        .mobile-border-top{
        border-top: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
        }
        
        input[type=checkbox]:checked + .content{
        max-height:500px !important;
        }
        .content{
        max-height:0px;
        overflow:hidden;
        -moz-transition:all 500ms ease;
        -ms-transition:all 500ms ease;
        -o-transition:all 500ms ease;
        -webkit-transition:all 500ms ease;
        transition:all 500ms ease;
        }
        }
        
        @media yahoo {
        .yh {
        display: none !important;
        }
        .mby20 {
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        }
        }
        
        .cta-td {
        background-color: #222222;
        color: #ffffff;
        padding: 12px 36px;
        border-radius: 3px;
        }
        .cta-td-small {
        background-color: #222222;
        color: #ffffff;
        padding: 12px 24px;
        border-radius: 3px;
        }
        .cta-td-none {
        background-color: #222222;
        color: #ffffff;
        padding: 12px 0px;
        border-radius: 3px;
        }
        .cta-td a {
        background-color: #222222;
        color: #ffffff;
        display: block;
        text-decoration: none;
        border-radius: 3px;
        }
        
        @font-face {
        font-family: 'Nunito';
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: 400;
        src: local('Nunito Regular'), local('Nunito-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/nunito/v9/XRXV3I6Li01BKofINeaBTMnFcQ.woff2) format('woff2');
        unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
        }
        @font-face {
        font-family: 'Nunito';
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: 700;
        src: local('Nunito Bold'), local('Nunito-Bold'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/nunito/v9/XRXW3I6Li01BKofAjsOUYevIWzgPDA.woff2) format('woff2');
        unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
    }</style>
</head>
<body style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; line-height: normal; background: #fff; height: 100% !important; width: 100% !important; margin: 0 !important; padding: 0 !important;" data-new-gr-c-s-check-loaded="14.1113.0" data-gr-ext-installed=""><div ems:preheader="" style="display:none!important;font-size:1px;color:#333333;line-height:1px;max-height:0px;max-width:0px;opacity:0;overflow:hidden;mso-hide:all">Lorem Ipsum</div><table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"><tbody><tr><td align="center"><font face="Arial, Helvetica" size="1" style="font-size:9px;color:#6d6d6d">Om e-postmeddelandet inte visas på rätt sätt kopierar följande länk till webbläsaren:<br> <a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank"><font face="Arial, Helvetica" size="1" style="font-size:9px;color:#6d6d6d; text-decoration: none;">https://www.google.com</font></a><br></font></td></tr></tbody></table>
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; line-height: normal; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; border-spacing: 0; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; mso-margin-bottom-alt: 0; mso-margin-top-alt: 0; border-collapse: collapse !important;">
        <tbody><tr>
            <td align="center" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; line-height: normal; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; border-spacing: 0; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; mso-margin-bottom-alt: 0; mso-margin-top-alt: 0; border-collapse: collapse !important;">
                <table class="fw" width="660" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; line-height: normal; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; border-spacing: 0; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; mso-margin-bottom-alt: 0; mso-margin-top-alt: 0; border-collapse: collapse !important;">
                    <tbody><tr>
                        <td align="center" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; line-height: normal; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; border-spacing: 0; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; mso-margin-bottom-alt: 0; mso-margin-top-alt: 0; border-collapse: collapse !important;">
                            <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" e-block-id="5bc6ed5e2f6aa7dbd0000001" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; line-height: normal; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; border-spacing: 0; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; mso-margin-bottom-alt: 0; mso-margin-top-alt: 0; border-collapse: collapse !important;">
                                
                                <tbody><tr>
                                    <td style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; line-height: normal; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; border-spacing: 0; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; mso-margin-bottom-alt: 0; mso-margin-top-alt: 0; border-collapse: collapse !important;">
                                        <!--[if !mso 9]><!-->
                                        <label class="dh" for="button" onclick="" style="display: none; overflow: auto; cursor: pointer; border-bottom: 1px solid #e0e0e0;">
                                            <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="15" cellspacing="0" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; line-height: normal; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; border-spacing: 0; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; mso-margin-bottom-alt: 0; mso-margin-top-alt: 0; border-collapse: collapse !important;">
                                                <tbody><tr>
                                                    <td align="left" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; line-height: normal; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; border-spacing: 0; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; mso-margin-bottom-alt: 0; mso-margin-top-alt: 0; border-collapse: collapse !important;">
                                                        <font e-editable="name" class="text-body text-base text-brand text-bold" style="color: #5e2674; font-family: Nunito, sans-serif; font-weight: bold; font-size: 14px; line-height: 20px;">KATEGORIER</font>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td align="right" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; line-height: normal; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; border-spacing: 0; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; mso-margin-bottom-alt: 0; mso-margin-top-alt: 0; border-collapse: collapse !important;">
                                                        <font class="text-body text-base text-brand" style="color: #5e2674; font-family: Nunito, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; line-height: 20px;">☰</font>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                </tbody></table>
                                        </label>
                                        <input id="button" type="checkbox" style="mso-hide:all; display:none !important; max-height:0px; overflow:hidden;">
                                        <!--<![endif]-->
                                        <div class="content">
                                            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; line-height: normal; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; border-spacing: 0; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; mso-margin-bottom-alt: 0; mso-margin-top-alt: 0; border-collapse: collapse !important;">
                                                <tbody><tr>
                                                    <td align="center" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; line-height: normal; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; border-spacing: 0; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; mso-margin-bottom-alt: 0; mso-margin-top-alt: 0; border-collapse: collapse !important;">
                                                        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="fw" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; line-height: normal; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; border-spacing: 0; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; mso-margin-bottom-alt: 0; mso-margin-top-alt: 0; border-collapse: collapse !important;">
                                                            <tbody><tr>
                                                                <td align="center" class="fl" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; line-height: normal; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; border-spacing: 0; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; mso-margin-bottom-alt: 0; mso-margin-top-alt: 0; border-collapse: collapse !important;">
                                                                    <table border="0" cellpadding="8" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; line-height: normal; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; border-spacing: 0; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; mso-margin-bottom-alt: 0; mso-margin-top-alt: 0; border-collapse: collapse !important;">
                                                                        <tbody><tr>
                                                                            <td align="center" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; line-height: normal; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; border-spacing: 0; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; mso-margin-bottom-alt: 0; mso-margin-top-alt: 0; border-collapse: collapse !important;">
                                                                                <a e-editable="“link1Url”" href="https://www.google.com" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; line-height: normal; text-decoration: none; font-weight: normal; color: #5e2674;" target="_blank"><span e-editable="“link1Label”" class="text-body text-base text-brand text-bold" style="color: #5e2674; font-family: Nunito, sans-serif; font-weight: bold; font-size: 14px; line-height: 20px;">DOFT</span></a>
                                                                            </td>
                                                                        </tr>
                                                                        </tbody></table>
                                                                </td>
                                                                <td height="1" width="1" bgcolor="#e0e0e0" class="dh fl" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; line-height: normal; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; border-spacing: 0; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; mso-margin-bottom-alt: 0; mso-margin-top-alt: 0; display: none; border-collapse: collapse !important;">
                                                                    <img src="./trans.gif" class="trans" width="1" height="1" style="-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; border: 0; outline: none; text-decoration: none; margin: 0; display: block; line-height: 0;">
                                                                </td>
                                                                <td align="center" class="fl" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; line-height: normal; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; border-spacing: 0; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; mso-margin-bottom-alt: 0; mso-margin-top-alt: 0; border-collapse: collapse !important;">
                                                                    <table border="0" cellpadding="8" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; line-height: normal; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; border-spacing: 0; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; mso-margin-bottom-alt: 0; mso-margin-top-alt: 0; border-collapse: collapse !important;">
                                                                        <tbody><tr>
                                                                            <td align="center" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; line-height: normal; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; border-spacing: 0; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; mso-margin-bottom-alt: 0; mso-margin-top-alt: 0; border-collapse: collapse !important;">
                                                                                <a e-editable="“link2Url”" href="https://www.google.com" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; line-height: normal; text-decoration: none; font-weight: normal; color: #5e2674;" target="_blank"><span e-editable="“link2Label”" class="text-body text-base text-brand text-bold" style="color: #5e2674; font-family: Nunito, sans-serif; font-weight: bold; font-size: 14px; line-height: 20px;">HUDVÅRD</span></a>
                                                                            </td>
                                                                        </tr>
                                                                        </tbody></table>
                                                                </td>
                                                                <td height="1" width="1" bgcolor="#e0e0e0" class="dh fl" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; line-height: normal; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; border-spacing: 0; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; mso-margin-bottom-alt: 0; mso-margin-top-alt: 0; display: none; border-collapse: collapse !important;">
                                                                    <img src="./trans.gif" class="trans" width="1" height="1" style="-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; border: 0; outline: none; text-decoration: none; margin: 0; display: block; line-height: 0;">
                                                                </td>
                                                                <td align="center" class="fl" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; line-height: normal; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; border-spacing: 0; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; mso-margin-bottom-alt: 0; mso-margin-top-alt: 0; border-collapse: collapse !important;">
                                                                    <table border="0" cellpadding="8" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; line-height: normal; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; border-spacing: 0; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; mso-margin-bottom-alt: 0; mso-margin-top-alt: 0; border-collapse: collapse !important;">
                                                                        <tbody><tr>
                                                                            <td align="center" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; line-height: normal; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; border-spacing: 0; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; mso-margin-bottom-alt: 0; mso-margin-top-alt: 0; border-collapse: collapse !important;">
                                                                                <a e-editable="“link3Url”" href="https://www.google.com" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; line-height: normal; text-decoration: none; font-weight: normal; color: #5e2674;" target="_blank"><span e-editable="“link3Label”" class="text-body text-base text-brand text-bold" style="color: #5e2674; font-family: Nunito, sans-serif; font-weight: bold; font-size: 14px; line-height: 20px;">HÅRVÅRD</span></a>
                                                                            </td>
                                                                        </tr>
                                                                        </tbody></table>
                                                                </td>
                                                                <td height="1" width="1" bgcolor="#e0e0e0" class="dh fl" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; line-height: normal; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; border-spacing: 0; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; mso-margin-bottom-alt: 0; mso-margin-top-alt: 0; display: none; border-collapse: collapse !important;">
                                                                    <img src="./trans.gif" class="trans" width="1" height="1" style="-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; border: 0; outline: none; text-decoration: none; margin: 0; display: block; line-height: 0;">
                                                                </td>
                                                                <td align="center" class="fl" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; line-height: normal; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; border-spacing: 0; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; mso-margin-bottom-alt: 0; mso-margin-top-alt: 0; border-collapse: collapse !important;">
                                                                    <table border="0" cellpadding="8" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; line-height: normal; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; border-spacing: 0; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; mso-margin-bottom-alt: 0; mso-margin-top-alt: 0; border-collapse: collapse !important;">
                                                                        <tbody><tr>
                                                                            <td align="center" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; line-height: normal; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; border-spacing: 0; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; mso-margin-bottom-alt: 0; mso-margin-top-alt: 0; border-collapse: collapse !important;">
                                                                                <a e-editable="“link4Url”" href="https://www.google.com" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; line-height: normal; text-decoration: none; font-weight: normal; color: #5e2674;" target="_blank"><span e-editable="“link4Label”" class="text-body text-base text-brand text-bold" style="color: #5e2674; font-family: Nunito, sans-serif; font-weight: bold; font-size: 14px; line-height: 20px;">MAKEUP</span></a>
                                                                            </td>
                                                                        </tr>
                                                                        </tbody></table>
                                                                </td>
                                                                <td height="1" width="1" bgcolor="#e0e0e0" class="dh fl" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; line-height: normal; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; border-spacing: 0; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; mso-margin-bottom-alt: 0; mso-margin-top-alt: 0; display: none; border-collapse: collapse !important;">
                                                                    <img src="./trans.gif" class="trans" width="1" height="1" style="-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; border: 0; outline: none; text-decoration: none; margin: 0; display: block; line-height: 0;">
                                                                </td>
                                                                <td align="center" class="fl" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; line-height: normal; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; border-spacing: 0; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; mso-margin-bottom-alt: 0; mso-margin-top-alt: 0; border-collapse: collapse !important;">
                                                                    <table border="0" cellpadding="8" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; line-height: normal; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; border-spacing: 0; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; mso-margin-bottom-alt: 0; mso-margin-top-alt: 0; border-collapse: collapse !important;">
                                                                        <tbody><tr>
                                                                            <td align="center" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; line-height: normal; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; border-spacing: 0; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; mso-margin-bottom-alt: 0; mso-margin-top-alt: 0; border-collapse: collapse !important;">
                                                                                <a e-editable="“link5Url”" href="https://www.google.com" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; line-height: normal; text-decoration: none; font-weight: normal; color: #5e2674;" target="_blank"><span e-editable="“link5Label”" class="text-body text-base text-brand text-bold" style="color: #5e2674; font-family: Nunito, sans-serif; font-weight: bold; font-size: 14px; line-height: 20px;">NYHETER</span></a>
                                                                            </td>
                                                                        </tr>
                                                                        </tbody></table>
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                            </tbody></table>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td height="1" bgcolor="#e0e0e0" class="trans-td" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; border-spacing: 0; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; mso-margin-bottom-alt: 0; mso-margin-top-alt: 0; line-height: 0; border-collapse: collapse !important;">
                                                        <img src="./trans.gif" class="trans" width="1" height="1" style="-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; border: 0; outline: none; text-decoration: none; margin: 0; display: block; line-height: 0;">
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                </tbody></table>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                </tbody></table>
                                
                                
                                
                                
                                
                                
                        </tbody></table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody></table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table>    
</body></html>
```

Comment: provide HTML code for checking the structure of your Hamburger menu.

Comment: @QuantumX I just did. Please look at the update section. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is fixed. I can't upload the all the codes here becaues of the body character limitation. But here are the changes I have made:

1. Remove/Make comment of .fl class from the media query (at 224 line)

```
/* .fl{
    width: 100% !important;
    display: block !important;
} */
```

2. Remove/Make comment of .content class from the media query (at 250 line)

```
/* .content{
    max-height:0px;
    overflow:hidden;
    -moz-transition:all 500ms ease;
    -ms-transition:all 500ms ease;
    -o-transition:all 500ms ease;
    -webkit-transition:all 500ms ease;
    transition:all 500ms ease;
} */
```

3. Set the table (at 324 line) style to "display: none;" at the end of the style with inline CSS.

[image]

Comment: Hi again, I have tried your code. Once you reduce the size of the windows under 660px the entire menu disappears. We still wanted to keep the menu and the links we just did not want it to turn into the hamburger menu.

Comment: OK, I got your html and fixed it. You can check my answer now :)

Comment: Thank you so much! You cracked the code. If I needed more help I'll create a new question.